# UITextView is leaving right margin while resizing on pinch effect

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, ios-simulator

I am trying to give a pinch effect on UITextView, so that user can resize it according to his need.

I am facing problem that when textView grows and then shrinks again the text is leaving a large right margin and is looking weird. The right margin is increasing every time textView is resized from bigger to smaller size.

Following is the code I am using for pinch effect:

```
- (void)pinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
       initialFrame = textEdit.frame;
    }

    CGFloat factor = gestureRecognizer.scale;
    CGAffineTransform zt = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, factor, factor);
    CGRect newframe = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(initialFrame, zt);
    [textEdit setFrame:CGRectMake(initialFrame.origin.x, initialFrame.origin.y, newframe.size.width, newframe.size.height)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIWebview for displaying text..It's have automatic zoom in and zoom out features.

Comment: but I need the user to type in texts.